# do flash supported in all major browser(window,android,ios,mac)?

Tags: android, ios, macos, flash

i am developing PHP/MYSQL/HTML based website, my website contains flash content, i have used flash based audio recorder on my website.

user will access my website from any device like window PC/phone, mac, android, i phone , i pad.

i want to know, flash content will be loaded on these devices without any issues or will need to install any plugin

forcing user to install plugin is not the right thing

and if using flash is not the right thing, what are the other options for audio recorder ?

Comment: not supported on android and iOS

Comment: @RahulTiwari : flash will be loaded on android IOS browser, by default these browser support flash or additional plugin required ?

Comment: android and iOS browsers do not support flash. by any official means.

Answer (score 1):

Flash is not available on anything but very old Android devices. 90% sure it's not available on iOS. Likewise, it's disappearing from desktop browsers as well.

Comment: i checked in iphone simulator, it is loading flash files ?!

Comment: iOS definitely doesn't support flash and as Tom says you can't even rely on desktops having it. Mine don't.